# Event Handler Not Getting Attached

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem with attaching event listeners to the dynamic list item elements created when I click one of three buttons. With the code in jsfiddle, I can add items to both lists but I can only remove list item elements from the first list (`ul#user`).

If I remove .first(), I can remove list item elements in both lists but this also means that every time I add a new list item, additional event handlers are being attached to the list items that already exist (i.e if I had an alert message instead of `$(this).remove()`, the message would appear multiple times depending on its position in the list and the number of list items I've added).

```
    <script src="js/scripts.js">

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $("button#hello").click(function() {
            $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Hello!</li>");
            $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Why hello there!</li>");
            $("ul").children("li").first().click(function() {
              $(this).remove();
            });
          });

          $("button#goodbye").click(function() {
            $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Goodbye!</li>");
            $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Goodbye, dear user!</li>");
            $("ul").children("li").first().click(function() {
              $(this).remove();
            })
          });

          $("button#stop").click(function() {
            $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Stop copying me!</li>");
            $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Pardon me. I meant no offense.</li>");
            $("ul").children("li").first().click(function() {
              $(this).remove();
            })
          });
        });

    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="hello">Say "hello"</button>
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="goodbye">Say "goodbye"</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="stop">Say "stop copying me!"</button>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>You said:</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled" id="user">

        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>The web page said back:</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled" id="webpage">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3vxf0622/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give details of your problem like what you want and what is happening in actual.

Comment: `...but only the first one. If I remove .first(),...` that's what `first()` does surprisingly - Can you try and explain a little more, it's not really clear what you expect to happen, you've only told us the problem and not the expected result.

Comment: Hello, sorry about that. I updated the original post to accurately reflect the issue that I am having.

Comment: Not Clear what are you trying to acheive.

Comment: Do you want to be able to click and have an event happen for every `<li>` in each list or just the first '<li>` in each list?

Comment: It should be for every `<li>` in each list. My understanding is that `.first()` just gets the first `<li>` every time the `.click' event happens on `<button>` (i.e which in this case is the newly generated `<li>`). The reason for this is to stop adding multiple copies of the same event handler onto an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a jQuery object from HTML, attach an event listener to it, then prepend it to your list.

For example:

```
var li = $("<li>Hello!</li>");
li.click(function(){
  // code here
});
$("#user").prepend(li);
```

This gives you finer control of your event handlers for new elements.

Comment: Wow, what an interesting way to accomplish this task. I never knew you could attach handlers this way. Thanks so much for the new method and for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use JQuery method .on() to handle dynamic elements added

check the fiddle for the implementation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("button#hello").click(function() {
    $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Hello!</li>");
    $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Why hello there!</li>");    
  });

  $("button#goodbye").click(function() {
    $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Goodbye!</li>");
    $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Goodbye, dear user!</li>");    
  });

  $("button#stop").click(function() {
    $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Stop copying me!</li>");
    $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Pardon me. I meant no offense.</li>");
  });

  // This handle list elements added dynamically and won't attach event handlers multiple times 
  $("ul").on("click","li",function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });  
  
  
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Talk to the web page</h1>
    <p>Click a button to say something to the web page. See what it says back!</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="hello">Say "hello"</button>
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" id="goodbye">Say "goodbye"</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="stop">Say "stop copying me!"</button>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>You said:</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled" id="user">

        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>The web page said back:</h2>
        <ul class="unstyled" id="webpage">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Satwiks/3vxf0622/1/

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment. That's exactly how I would do it but a tutorial I'm following suggests that the way that it's done in the OP is also a feasible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I hope it will help you..
Rather than registering event handlers to each `<li>` you can register event handler only on parent `<ul>`.In this way you don't need to register event handler for every new dynamically created `<li>`...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button#hello").click(function() {
        $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Hello!</li>");
        $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Why hello there!</li>");
    });

    $("button#goodbye").click(function() {
        $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Goodbye!</li>");
        $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Goodbye, dear user!</li>");
    });

    $("button#stop").click(function() {
        $("ul#user").prepend("<li>Stop copying me!</li>");
        $("ul#webpage").prepend("<li>Pardon me. I meant no offense.</li>");
    });

    $('ul').click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(event.target).remove();
    });
});
```

Here is working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qy4a54hk/)